# How to make signInWithProvider work in Android with my OIDC provider?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, openid-connect

I am trying to implement login using the OIDC provider for which I followed the official doc at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/openid-connect?hl=en&authuser=0#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk

When I tap the login button which executes the `startActivityForSignInWithProvider` method, I see my status bar flash for brief milliseconds and get an exception in the LogCat:
**There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash.**

[Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Fv4.png)

Did a lot of research but to no avail. All the topics point to adding SHA-1/SHA-256 which I have already added on the Firebase Console.

Also tried to run the sample app at:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth

This also gave me the same error and the status bar just flashes each time I tap the login button.

Here is my code:

```
class LoginWithFirebaseOidcActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginWithFirebaseOidcBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityLoginWithFirebaseOidcBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        auth = Firebase.auth

        binding.btnLoginWithLiberland.setOnClickListener {
            // Login using Firebase OIDC library
            loginUsingFirebaseOidc()
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        updateUI(currentUser)

        // Look for a pending auth result
        val pending = auth.pendingAuthResult
        if (pending != null) {
            pending.addOnSuccessListener { authResult ->
                Log.d(TAG, "checkPending:onSuccess:$authResult")
                updateUI(authResult.user)
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.w(TAG, "checkPending:onFailure", e)
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "checkPending: null")
        }
    }

    private fun loginUsingFirebaseOidc() {
        Log.i(TAG, "loginUsingFirebaseOidc() invoked")

        // Create authentication providers
        val providerBuilder = OAuthProvider.newBuilder("oidc.liberland-services-dev")
        providerBuilder.scopes = listOf("openid", "email", "profile", "phone_number")
        auth.startActivityForSignInWithProvider(this, providerBuilder.build())
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.i(TAG, "AuthResult: $it")
                // User is signed in.
                // IdP data available in
                // authResult.getAdditionalUserInfo().getProfile().
                // The OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
                // ((OAuthCredential)authResult.getCredential()).getAccessToken().
                // The OAuth secret can be retrieved by calling:
                // ((OAuthCredential)authResult.getCredential()).getSecret().
                updateUI(it.user)
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                // Handle failure.
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: ${e.message}")
                e.printStackTrace()
                binding.txtUserStatus.text = "Error logging in: ${e.message}"
                showToast("Error logging in: ${e.message}")
            }
    }

    private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {
        if (user != null) {
            binding.txtUserStatus.text = "Logged in as ${user.email}"
        } else {
            binding.txtUserStatus.text = "Login result will appear here"
        }
    }

    private fun showToast(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "LoginWithFirebaseOidcActivity"
    }
}
```

Tried retrieving `SHA-1` and `SHA-256` using the below command:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Added the `SHA-1` and `SHA-256` to the Firebase console.

To verify if the SHAs are correct, other auth methods like Login with Google and Deep Link are working in the app. The problem only happens with the `startActivityForSignInWithProvider` method.

The other method on the same doc `signInWithCredential` also works fine. But for this, I need to use a separate library to fetch the `IDToken` and then pass it `signInWithCredential` method.

I am expecting the login using `startActivityForSignInWithProvider` should work and give me a user object. Stuck on this for so many days, please help.